# Scala: List Operations

Tags: list, scala, functional-programming

In Scala, define the function slice(from, until, xs) that selects an interval of elements from the (string) list xs such that for each element x in the interval the following invariant holds: `from <= indexOf(x) < until`.

```
from: the lowest index to include from this list.
until: the highest index to exclude from this list.
```

returns: a list containing the elements greater than or equal to index from extending up to (but not including) index until of this list.

example:

```
def test {
    expect (Cons("b", Cons("c", Nil()))) {
      slice(1, 3, Cons("a", Cons("b", Cons("c", Cons("d", Cons("e", Nil()))))))
    }
  }
```

another example:

```
def test {
    expect (Cons("d", Cons("e", Nil()))) {
      slice(3, 7, Cons("a", Cons("b", Cons("c", Cons("d", Cons("e", Nil()))))))
    }
  }
```

and this is what I have, but its not that correct. Can someone help me with it?

```
 abstract class StringList
    case class Nil() extends StringList
    case class Cons(h: String, t: StringList) extends StringList

    object Solution { 

      // define function slice
      def slice(from : Int, until : Int, xs : StringList) : StringList = (from, until, xs) match {
        case (_,_,Nil()) => Nil()
        case (n, m, _) if(n == m) => Nil()
        case (n, m, _) if(n > m) => Nil()
        case (n, m, _) if(n < 0) => Nil()
        case (n, m, xs) if(n == 0)=> Cons(head(xs), slice(n+1,m,tail(xs)))
        case (n, m, xs) => {
          //Cons(head(xs), slice(n+1,m,tail(xs)))
          if(n == from) { 
            print("\n") 
            print("n == m " + Cons(head(xs), slice(n+1,m,tail(xs)))) 
            print("\n")  
            Cons(head(xs), slice(n+1,m,tail(xs)))
          }
          else slice(n+1,m,tail(xs))
        }
      }

      def head(t : StringList) : String = t match {
        case Nil() => throw new NoSuchElementException 
        case Cons(h, t) => h
      }

      def tail(t : StringList) : StringList = t match {
        case Nil() => Nil()
        case Cons(h, t) => t
      }

     /* def drop(n : Int, t : StringList) : StringList = (n, t) match {
        case (0, t) => t
        case (_, Nil()) => Nil()
        case (n, t) => drop(n-1 , tail(t))
      }*/

    }//
```

Comment: Can you expand on what is not correct about it? What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: well my code doesnt return the correct result. if you look at the example that I put inthere it returns something else and I am stuck and I dont know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works add a method to find the element at given index :

```
    trait StringList

  case class Nil() extends StringList

  case class Cons(h: String, t: StringList) extends StringList

  object Solution {

    def numberOfElements(str: StringList, count: Int = 0): Int = {
      if (str == Nil()) count else numberOfElements(tail(str), count + 1)
    }

    def elemAtIndex(n: Int, str: StringList, count: Int = 0): String = {
      if (str == Nil() || n == count) head(str) else elemAtIndex(n, tail(str), count + 1)
    }

    def head(str: StringList): String = str match {
      case Nil() => throw new NoSuchElementException
      case Cons(h, t) => h
    }

    def tail(str: StringList): StringList = str match {
      case Nil() => Nil()
      case Cons(h, t) => t
    }

    // define function slice
    def slice(from: Int, until: Int, xs: StringList): StringList = (from, until, xs) match {
      case (n, m: Int, _) if n == m || n > m || n < 0 => Nil()
      case (n, m: Int, xs: StringList) =>
        if (m > numberOfElements(xs)) {
          slice(n, numberOfElements(xs), xs)
        } else {
          Cons(elemAtIndex(n, xs), slice(n + 1, m, xs))
        }
    }
  }

scala> Solution.slice(1, 3, Cons("a", Cons("b", Cons("c", Cons("d", Cons("e", Nil()))))))
res0: StringList = Cons(b,Cons(c,Nil()))

scala> Solution.slice(3, 7, Cons("a", Cons("b", Cons("c", Cons("d", Cons("e", Nil()))))))
res0: StringList = Cons(d,Cons(e,Nil()))
```

Comment: your implementation is not fully correct, you code doesnt work with other examples, suck as this one: def test7 {
    expect (Cons("d", Cons("e", Nil()))) {
      slice(3, 7, Cons("a", Cons("b", Cons("c", Cons("d", Cons("e", Nil()))))))
    }
  }

Comment: it gives java.util.NoSuchElementException as expected because of the value of to = 7. as it was not mentioned in the requirement. but i have edited according  to your need.